# Problema con función BUSCAR en excel

Tags: excel, funciones

estoy teniendo un problema con la función BUSCAR de excel y el problema es que me coge unos valores mal y otros bien. Pongo imágenes para explicarlo mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que se hagan una idea, en el campo Código necesito mostrar la letra de la nota buscándolo en la parte inferior de la tabla. La función que tengo ahora mismo es la siguiente `=BUSCAR(G2;B9:F11;B11:F11)`, pero como pueden ver en las celdas H3 y H4 no me lo hace correctamente. ¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

Comment: Esta re buena tu pregunta jaja, hice la prueba de armar ese mismo excel, y me sucede lo mismo. Pense que podias llegar a tener algo mal en la formula entonces use busqueda matricial que es mas sencilla ``=BUSCAR(G3; {"Insuficiente","Suficiente","Bien","Notable","Sobresaliente";"I","Sf","B","N","Sb"})`` Y aun asi me sigue devolviendo los mismos valores que a vos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función BUSCAR exige que el tercer argumento, el vector de comparación, debe ser de 1 sola dimensión, es decir, 1 sola fila o 1 sola columna.

Además, los valores **deben estar ordenados alfabéticamente** o si son números, **en orden ascendente**.

> [Función
>   BUSCAR](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/buscar-funci%C3%B3n-buscar-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

Usa mejor siempre BUSCARV o BUSCARH. En este caso, viene mejor usar BUSCARH.

Además, usa referencias absolutas para bloquear el rango de celdas en el que miras el valor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en H2 es:

```
=BUSCARH(G2;$B$9:$F$11;3;FALSO)
```

Y como ves en la imagen, funciona perfectamente.

Te recomiendo que investigues sobre BUSCARV y BUSCARH.